# Populate diiferent type of arraylist in same adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with `RecyclerView`, the adapter and XML is the same for `RecyclerView` in 3 activities. The issue is in `getItemCount()` because 3 different types of `ArrayList` is populated within the same adapter.

How can I use different types of `ArrayList` with the same adapter?

Comment: what is the issue with `getItemCount()` ????

Comment: Please explain a bit more the problem that you have and provide some code.

Comment: what do you mean by 3 different types of ArrayList? that the objects contained in them are instances of a different class for each?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView Check if this helps.

Comment: I mean to say i have 3 different model class each arraylist are of specific model class type (generic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create 3 Getter-Setter. e.g.
`ModelA` , `ModelB`, `ModelC`

Now create a arraylist of `Object` which accept any type of class object. e.g

```
ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now add your models in `objectList` when you needed like `objectList.add(modelA);` 
here `modelA` is object of `ModelA` class.

Now you have to use this `objectList` in your adapter and then the main part comes, You have to create conditions in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method. Like this,

```
if(objectList.get(position) instanceof ModelA){
     //TODo your ModelA operations
}else if (objectList.get(position) instanceof ModelB){
     //TODo your ModelB operations
}else if (objectList.get(position) instanceof ModelC){
     //TODo your ModelC operations
}
```

This works for you because you have same layout for all otherwise you have to play with `ViewTypes`

Answer (score 1):

This adapter class implementation can give you some idea of what you want to achieve

```
class GenericAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GenericAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<?> data;

    GenericAdapter(List<?> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(data.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ...
        ...

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // bind the view references
            ...
            ...
        }


        void bindData(Object data) {
            if (data instanceof Model1) {
                // bind data for model class 1
                ...
                ...
            } else if (data instanceof Model2) {
                // bind data for model class 2
                ...
                ...
            } else if (data instanceof Model3) {
                // bind data for model class 3
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build an Interface which is implemented by the 3 ArrayList extensions you created and that contains the method you need for the recycler adapter.